# "googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError" when setting up a GKE environment using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/gke. The only change I've made to the repository is to define a project name which is equal to the result of `gcloud config get-value project`:

```
kurtpeek@Kurts-MacBook-Pro ~/g/s/g/k/learn-terraform-provision-gke-cluster (master)> git diff
diff --git a/terraform.tfvars b/terraform.tfvars
index a13174b..4f7eaae 100644
--- a/terraform.tfvars
+++ b/terraform.tfvars
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-project_id = "REPLACE_ME"
+project_id = "kurtpeek-179513"
 region     = "us-central1"
kurtpeek@Kurts-MacBook-Pro ~/g/s/g/k/learn-terraform-provision-gke-cluster (master)> 
gcloud config get-value project
kurtpeek-179513
```

However, if I run `terraform apply` I get logs that end with this error:

```
Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

google_compute_network.vpc: Creating...
google_compute_network.vpc: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_compute_network.vpc: Creation complete after 23s [id=projects/kurtpeek-179513/global/networks/kurtpeek-179513-vpc]
google_compute_subnetwork.subnet: Creating...
google_compute_subnetwork.subnet: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_subnetwork.subnet: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_compute_subnetwork.subnet: Creation complete after 23s [id=projects/kurtpeek-179513/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/kurtpeek-179513-subnet]
google_container_cluster.primary: Creating...
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
google_container_cluster.primary: Still creating... [1m0s elapsed]

Error: googleapi: Error 500: Internal error encountered., backendError

  on gke.tf line 17, in resource "google_container_cluster" "primary":
  17: resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
```

According to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20029, this can be due to an incorrect project name, but I believe I have set that variable as instructed (https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/gke#update-your-terraform-tfvars-file). Any idea what might be causing this? (The Terraform project code is available at https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-provision-gke-cluster).

Comment: Would you mind posting the `gke.tf` file?

Comment: Sure, it's at https://github.com/hashicorp/learn-terraform-provision-gke-cluster/blob/master/gke.tf.

Comment: Very interesting. Does `terraform plan` show everything as expected? You could try and save the plan to a file and run apply using the saved plan file, just to see if it will make any difference.

Comment: How exactly do you replace your `project_id` value ? Is it hardcoded or you use somewhere `gcloud config get-value project` as command substitution ? And where is the `var` variable configured ? Could you post the actual content of `terraform.tfvars` file ?